# Variable 'foo' does not exist in template

Tags: templating, error-message, variable, server

I've uploaded my site to the live server and i'm getting

```
Template Error

Variable "heading" does not exist
```

On a couple of pages. This is only happening to 2 sections, the rest are all fine.

and it then goes onto identify the template and template var that it claims is missing.

But, there is no db or file difference to the local or dev sites!

I've cleared caches, double checked permissions, changed php versions to no avail. Any ideas?

Update, i had devmode set to true, and have set it to false now, but, now the page renders, it does not output any text content from the cms. Just an image. Odd.

Comment: John, is your issue related to [this recent bug](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/5131/45)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, oddly, the answer was instead of {{ heading }} i needed to do {{ entry.heading }}

Very odd.